# Counting frequencies across multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, frequency-distribution

I have several dataframes with similar columns:

```
df1
name, age, state

df2
name, age, state
```

and so on.

How can I count frequency occurrences of age values from age column across all dataframes? Something like:

```
Age  Count
42   23
38   20
..   ..
```

Thank you!

Comment: concatenate , and than use value count for age columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count occurrence of a value across multiple data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870997/how-to-count-occurrence-of-a-value-across-multiple-data-frames)

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df1])["Age"].value_counts().reset_index(name="Count")`

Comment: @Erfan Thank you! In case of random or large number of dataframes will looping through the dataframes work inside the concat?

Comment: Yes, you can create a list beforehand, or with list comprehension inside the concat like so: `pd.concat([df for df in list_of_dfs if ...])` for example.

Comment: @Qudus, thanks but link is about R, not python.

Comment: @Erfan yes exactly what I'm trying to do but getting "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".  Dataframes are generated from csv files into dict and they have dynamically assigned names, like df[0], df[1] and so on. Therefore age column is df[0]["age"].  Putting this into pd.concat()  produces TypeError. I'm clearly missing something, just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: @ikechi So, you have a list of dataframes named in the format `df[0], df[1], df[2], ...` ?  If so, have you tried `pd.concat(df)` ?  Is it returning the concatenated dataframes by row ?

Comment: @SeaBean Thanks, got it working exactly this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat the dataframes, then use [`GroupBy.count()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) to get the counts by age, as follows:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).groupby('age')['age'].count().reset_index(name='Count')
```